# How to fix "× TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm making a netflix clone app in nodejs and got stuck on generateMedia function.

On TabContentOne.js file, On `import { generateMedia } from 'react-media-query'`  it is dotted and when I run `npm install @types/react-media-query` it gives me errors. I did `npm i react-media-query`.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Button } from './Button';
import { generateMedia } from 'react-media-query'

// Media Query 
const customMedia = generateMedia({
    smDesktop: '1440px',
    tablet: '960px'
})
```

This is the link from my bitbucket https://bitbucket.org/danclaudiu95/nodejs-reactjs.git
I'm expecting to use generateMedia function the put style on some elements in my application but the npm server doesn't start anymore.

Comment: Where did you get `import { generateMedia } from 'react-media-query'` from.  I don't see a library called react-media-query anywhere including your package.json.  did you mean to use `styled-media-query` instead?

Comment: The package "react-media-query" seems to be quite old "5 years ago". Why are you using it in a new project? You don't even have it listed in your dependencies...

Comment: @YuryTarabanko can you link the library for 'react-media-query'?  I only see one for react-media.

Comment: @ruby_newbie Sure https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-media-query

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using another package that does the same thing, "react-media-query" is outdated and removed from github.